# CSS ::after if visible at start then disseapering at middle and reappearing at end why?

Tags: html, css

CSS `::after` if visible at the start then disappearing in the middle and reappearing at the end why? I want it to be visible throughout the animation equally like a horizontal slider

Here is my code:

```css
.btn {
  all: inherit;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.btn::after {
  overflow: visible !important;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -5%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2%;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  animation-name: LeftToRight;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes LeftToRight {
  0% {
    left: -5%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 105%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">UNIVERSE</button>
```

Comment: I checked the codepen, seems fine to me? try to increase the duration and check if it really did disappear

Comment: Hm I don't know what is happening, when I save it works fine for like 3-4 iterations  then again it gives a shuttering  and disappears effect, the problem is the same in my  VScode as well

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm on a mac and this works with both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I just checked it on firefox, chrome, and opera. it's all good. anyway, give it a higher `z-index` and see what happens.